# can't get justifyContent to work with flexbox and material ui

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to return some jsx to the title prop of the material-ui card component. I would like the two boxes to appear with space between them. i.e. one on the left side and one on the right side of the header.

The flex box is displaying the divs inline as expected, but I can't get them to move across the horizontal axis. attached is a picture of what it looks like atm.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8fTE.png)

```
renderCardTitle() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <div>
                first box
            </div>
            <div style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
                second box
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

the code for the card component in question is:

```
 <Card style={styles.cardStyles}>
      <CardHeader
      title={this.renderCardTitle()}
      actAsExpander
      showExpandableButton
      />
      <CardText expandable>
        details about the quiz
      </CardText>
     </Card>
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you apply a width: 100% to your div?

Comment: added width 100% to the parent using the textStyle prop. Then changed from inline-flex to flex. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers given helped to find a problem which was two fold:

1) the parent div was not set to width 100%, to override the inline style of the card title text component use the text style prop of the card header component, as documented on the material ui docs http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card

```
      <CardHeader
      title={this.renderCardTitle()}
      actAsExpander
      showExpandableButton
      textStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
      />
```

2) as mentioned in one of the answers, also need to use flex instead of inline-flex, as inline flex collapses to the size of the content it contains.

Answer (score 3):

`display: inline-flex` will collapse their parent to content size, hence the `justify-content` won't work, so use `display: flex` instead

```css
body > div {
  padding: 5px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <div>
    first box
  </div>
  <div>
    second box
  </div>
</div>
```

Or give the parent a width wider than the 2 boxes content

```css
body > div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <div>
    first box
  </div>
  <div>
    second box
  </div>
</div>
```

Or add a margin on the 2:nd box

```css
body > div {
  padding: 5px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-flex;">
  <div>
    first box
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
    second box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! there was a combination of problems. Firstly as you said inline-flex was collapsing to the size of the content (changed to flex instead). In addition, the parent div was not 100% width. I overode those using the textStyle prop of the CardHeader, and setting the width to 100%.

Comment: how does it work now? Do you slightly edit your answer to include the specifics of the question and I mark that as the answer? Or do I write a modal answer based on yours?

Comment: @LuckyLukas First, since my answer solve the main issue I don't see the point updating, second, any parent (that does not have 100% width) is not even mentioned in the question, and doesn't effect the justify-content property, .. so based on that I don't see why you should post an answer of your own when mine already answered the main, origin question

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't solve the main issue. After changing to flex it didn't alter how the page looked as its parent wasn't 100% and needed to be through a material ui specific prop. So thought I would provide that info to anyone having the same problem. But yer probably should have just commented. I'm new, didn't know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LuckyLukas You are missing my point. You ask why `justifyContent` does not work and I explained and showed that, hence my answer solved your question. .... Now you also say your layout does not look how it did prior changing to `display: flex`, though that is a completely different issue, which isn't even mentioned in your original question and has nothing to do with how `justify-content` work, but even so, in my second sample I mentioned giving the parent a width could be a solution, so basically I covered that too, so based on above one does not post a self answer, one accept the other

Answer (score 1):

It may be the top div's width. It is not spanning the whole Card Header container. Try setting the `width:'100%'`.

```
renderCardTitle() {
return (
  <div style={{ width:'100%' display: 'inline-flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <div>
            first box
        </div>
        <div style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
            second box
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```